# Assembly Language: How to include the decimal places on the next instruction after dividing?

Tags: assembly, floating-point

Good day. My project is about computing BMI using inches and pounds. So the user will input his height in inches and weight in pounds. I have already learned dividing and multiplying. I just don't know how to include the decimal points after dividing, because I have to multiply it again by 703, and only the whole number is multiplied by 703.

```
n1 dw 0
n2 dw 0

;gets input from user

xor dx, dx
mov ax, n1    ;n1 is the weight and n2 is the height so i'm dividing them
mov bx, n2
div bx
mov bx, ax    ;answer is stored in bx
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Assuming x86 architecture, you're doing integer division (and probably multiplication as well). Floating point arithmetic in assembler uses special instructions (and special registers).

Comment: I can't find any good reference programs using Floating point arithmetic. I found the instructions but can't find a program using them.

Comment: If you multiply before you divide,you can do it all with integers.

Comment: You can do the computations with scaled integers (10 times or 100 times the real value) and then just insert a decimal separator when displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Using fixed-point notation, to obtain a result of division with fractional part, you can write:

```
 Mov   AX,n1
 XOr   CX,CX
{AX:CX contains the integer number to divide by n2}
 Mov   BX,n2
{BX contains the integer number that divides}
 XOr   DX,DX
 Div   BX
 XChg  AX,CX
 Div   BX
{CX:AX contains the result of division (AX is the fractional part)}
```

But, as said by prl, is better first multiply and then divide.
The division, however, is maded always with two "div" instruction fore this reason: when the result of a DIV instruction can't be contained into AX's register, a "division by zero" interrupt's call is invoked.
After MUL you have a 32 bit number DX:AX, that can be divided by n2 as follows:

```
 Mov   CX,AX
 MOV   AX,DX
{AX:CX contains the result of multiplication}
 Mov   BX,n2
{BX contains the integer number that divides}
 XOr   DX,DX
 Div   BX
 XChg  AX,CX
 Div   BX
{CX:AX contains the result of division}
```

Also, to do a inch to cm conversion (and similar), you can multiply for a fixed point number that represent the scale factor:

```
{cm=inch*028A3DH (2.54)}

 MOV AX,08A3DH
 MOV BX,Inch
 XOR CX,CX
 MUL BX
 ADD DX,BX
 ADC CX,CX
 ADD DX,BX
 ADC CX,0

{CX:DX:AX= cm (AX is the fractional part)}
```